# How to call a main function in a linked executable written in C from NASM with argc,argv,envp supplied correctly

Tags: c, assembly, linker, nasm

I am linking a C program to a NASM executable. The assembly file invokes the main function in the linked C program

```
virus:  infect.c virus.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

virus.o: virus.asm template.asm.inc
    $(ASM) $(AFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

What I tried:

The `infect.c` contains the main function in this manner:

```
int main(int argc, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat st;
    int vfd, xfd, magic;
    pid_t pid;
    off_t offset;
    ino_t inode;

    vfd = open(argv[0], O_RDONLY);
    ...
```

Since I want to call the `main` function in `infect.c` from `virus.asm`. The main function should *infact* be in the `virus.asm` and since there cannot be two main functions in a executable I changed the `main` function in `infect.c` to

```
int infect(int argc, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat st;
    int vfd, xfd, magic;
    pid_t pid;
    off_t offset;
    ino_t inode;

    vfd = open(argv[0], O_RDONLY);
    ...
```

1) I do not know how to call this infact function from the NASM assembly, this is what i tried in `virus.asm` file

```
extern infect
main:
    call infect
```

The program runs, however it doesn't produce the desired effect. The `infect.c` is an ELF virus that is supposed to look for files in CWD and infect them.

2) The issue seems to be the `int argc, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]` that i'm not handling properly while calling

How do i properly call the function in `infect.c` from `virus.asm` with the `argc`, `argv` and `envp` supplied in order for the program to work correctly?

Comment: You could rename the function in virus.asm to virus_main and set the entry point to virus_main, which is defaulted to main.

Comment: @cmdLP thank you, how do I set the entry point to virus_main? Do I remain leave the infect() in the infect.c or should I change that to main?

Comment: You must also set the arguments. See section Function Calling Sequence in [SystemV ps ABI AMD64](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.95.pdf) => set rax to argc, rsi to argv and rdi envb

Comment: You pass the entry point to the assembler/linker with a switch like `/entry` or `-e`.

Comment: @Oliv if I rename the main the virus.asm to virus_main then where should I place the main function? And how do I ensure virus_main is executed first? Thank you

Comment: @cmdLP so do leave the main function in infect.c? Thanks! How would the calling the main function from asm look like do I need to provide arguments like arch argh envp

Comment: @KAKAK you inverted me and cmdLP. When the kernel launch the process, the process start at the entry point, and the state of the registers is describe in the SystemV ABI ps AMD64 section 3.4. See Figure 3.9 Initial process stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a _start entry point in an asm file. Bellow an example code that set argc, argv and envp for elf abi on AMD64, and linux kernel. It will not work with real code because it does not perform usual initialization process like setting fs segment for tls, initializing static variables etc... but it gives you a first taste of what need to be done!

Memo [argc -> %rdi ; argv -> %rsi ; envp -> %rdx ]

```
.global _start
.type _start,@function
.align 16
_start:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_undefined rip
/*nullify rbp as required by doc*/
    xor %rbp, %rbp
/*move argc to rdi and advance rsp*/
    popq %rdi
/*set argv*/
    movq %rsp, %rsi
/*now envp is at rsp+8*argc+8*/
    lea 8(%rsp, %rdi, 8), %rdx
/*realign stack*/
  push %rdi
/*push rsp to the stack*/
  callq main
/*call _exit at return*/
  movq %rax,%rdi
  mov $231, %rax
  syscall
  .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Instead of `sal` and so on, use `lea 8(%rsp, %rdi, 8), %rdx`.  Replacing mov+shl+add+add is a perfect use-case for LEA, and as a bonus it's actually calculating an address so that semantic meaning of the mnemonic actually applies.

Comment: You don't need to push anything before calling `main`; it doesn't have any stack args and zeroing `%rbp` before the call is all you need to terminate the linked list of frame pointers if `main` chooses to make a stack frame.  (And if not then there's no chain of saved frame pointers to follow). 
Also, `%rsp` is 16-byte aligned on entry to `_start` as guaranteed by the ABI, so if you want to `push %rsp` for some reason, you could just do that and overwrite `argc` returning RSP to 16-byte alignement.  Or just use a `mov` load and don't pop anything, just using `lea 8(%rsp), %rsi` for argv.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok I am a very beginner asm coder but I am going to try to implement what you say as an exercice!

Comment: `-15` is `0xff...f1`.  You meant `$-16`.  Fortunately it doesn't actually cause a problem because the stack is going to be 8-byte aligned at that point (after 1 pop from 16-byte alignment.)

Comment: Minor point: `xor %ebp, %ebp` is 1 byte shorter and does exactly the same thing.  Same for `mov %60, %eax`.  And `main`'s return value is an `int`, so you only need `mov %eax, %edi`.  Also, you should definitely use `SYS_exit_group` to exit all threads of the process, not just this one, when `main` returns.  `mov $231, %eax`.  But actually that's not right either, because **returning from `main` is supposed to flush I/O buffers and any other libc cleanup, like running `atexit` functions.  So you need to `call exit`** if you really want to write a `_start` that could actually work in general.

Comment: `hlt` is not particularly useful; it will segfault if you run it from user-space so you might as well let execution fall off the end if `exit` or `sys_exit_group` returns.  But they're not allowed to return so really you don't have to handle that.

Comment: @KAKAK: you need to tell it not to link the CRT start files if you're writing your own `_start`.  (But to still link libc because you use `open()` from C).  Use `gcc -nostartfiles main.c start.o -o myprog` to make a dynamically linked executable.  If you use `-static`, you'll need to make `_start` manually call glibc init functions first.  See [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](//stackoverflow.com/q/36861903) which covers `_start` vs. `main` as well as 32 vs. 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
_start:
    xor rbp, rbp
    pop rdi
    mov rsi, rsp
    lea rdx, [rsp+rdi+8*8]
    push rdi
    call main
    mov rdi, rax
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h
```

Execute this first thing in the _start function. If you need to execute later on ensure you save the following registers

```
; save initial program state
mov rbx, rsp 
mov r14, rdi
mov r15, rsi
```

then you can reload these registers and call the instruction above to call main

Comment: Don't use `int 80h` in 64-bit code.  Not all Linux kernels are built with `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Also, the "execute later" part is not clear.  If you want to do stuff before calling `main`, just leave argc and argv on the stack and run this whole block later.  RDI and RSI don't hold anything valuable on entry to `_start`, so you don't need to save them if you're going to run the `pop rdi` and so on right before the `call main`.

Comment: This looks like a translation of @Oliv's answer to NASM, but then you made it worse by using `int 80h` and `sys_exit` instead of `sys_exit_group`.  You don't credit that answer, even though this has all the same weird quirks like using `pop`/`push` instead of `mov edi, [rsp]`, and using `mov rdi, rax` even though `sys_exit` only takes a 32-bit arg.  Also you stripped out all the comments that explain argc, argv, and envp.